# Using Rapidshare API to check if a file is downloadable

Tags: php, api, rapidshare

I'm new with this API thing, so I don't know how to use it very well. I want to make an application on C or PHP or AppleScript to check if a file is downloadable. I just need to know how to send the request properly.

I read the API docs but I still don't know how to get the return values.

Can anyone help me?

Happy holidays everyone =)
since now thanks.

Comment: Checkout this blog post.Though it is written in Java but it may help you. It checks file status on rapidshare.com http://malhar2010.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-rapidsharecom-api-to-check-file.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like:

```
http://api.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=checkfiles_v1&type=prem&login=MY_USERNAME&
password=MY_PASSWORD&files=5044438&filenames=test1.rar
```

This call makes use of the checkfiles_v1 subroutine which according to the API documentation:

```
subroutine=checkfiles_v1
Description:    Gets status details about a list of given files. (files parameter limited to 3000 bytes. filenames parameter limited to 30000 bytes.)
Parameters:  files=comma separated list of file ids
             filenames=comma separated list of the respective filename. Example: files=50444381,50444382 filenames=test1.rar,test2.rar
                incmd5=if set to 1, field 7 is the hex-md5 of the file. This will double your points! If not given, all md5 values will be 0
Reply fields:
        1:File ID
        2:Filename
        3:Size (in bytes. If size is 0, this file does not exist.)
        4:Server ID
        5:Status integer, which can have the following numeric values:
            0=File not found
            1=File OK (Anonymous downloading)
            2=File OK (TrafficShare direct download without any logging)
            3=Server down
            4=File marked as illegal
            5=Anonymous file locked, because it has more than 10 downloads already
            6=File OK (TrafficShare direct download with enabled logging. Read our privacy policy to see what is logged.)
        6:Short host (Use the short host to get the best download mirror: http://rs$serverid$shorthost.rapidshare.com/files/$fileid/$filename)
        7:md5 (See parameter incmd5 in parameter description above.)
Reply format:   integer,string,integer,integer,integer,string,string
```

**You can make use of the Status from the reply and if its value is 1 it means the file is downloadable.**

Here goes the program in PHP:

[Click here to see the server reply](http://api.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=checkfiles_v1&files=293360186&filenames=1597494240.pdf)

```
<?php

// This PHP script check if a file is publicly downloadable
// I've taken a sample file: 
// http://rapidshare.com/files/293360186/1597494240.pdf
// which at the time of wring is available + is downloadable.

// File ID
$file_id = '293360186';

// Filename
$file_name = '1597494240.pdf';

//construct the URL.
$URL = "http://api.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=checkfiles_v1&files=$file_id&filenames=$file_name";

// Now get the response for this URL.
/* It looks something like:
   293360186,1597494240.pdf,6861070,59,1,gc,0 

   So we are just interested in field 5(Status), check if its 1(file downloadable) or 0
*/

$reply = file_get_contents($URL);
if(!$reply)
{
    die("Failed for $URL<br>");
}

$arr = explode(',',$reply);

if($arr[4] == 1)
    print "File $file_name is publicly downloadable<br>";
else
    print "File $file_name is not publicly downloadable<br>";

?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok but how do I store this Status in a variable? If possible give me an example in C or applescript or php.

Since now thanks,
Thiago.